# Why does this query fail with "Cannot convert a char value to money. "

Tags: sql, sql-server

Addendum: I don't have a clue as to why this has close votes because "the results are not reproducible." The schema and data script is provided and the script in question is provided. It's all there.

This query fails:

```
SELECT 
    P.Profession AS Profession,
    CASE
        WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 200000
            THEN 'wow'
        WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 100000 
             AND P.AverageAnnualSalary <= 199999
            THEN 'nice'
        WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 0 
             AND P.AverageAnnualSalary <= 99999
            THEN 'ok'
        ELSE P.AverageAnnualSalary
    END AS Description
FROM
    tProfession2 AS P
ORDER BY 
    Profession ASC
```

with this error:

> Msg 235, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

This query works:

```
SELECT Profession AS Profession,
       CASE 
           WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 200000 THEN 'wow'
           WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 100000 THEN 'nice'
           ELSE 'ok'
        END AS Description
FROM tProfession2 P
ORDER BY Profession ASC
```

This is the schema and data:

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tProfession2]    Script Date: 12/14/2021 10:48:41 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tProfession2](
    [ProfessionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Profession] [nchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [AverageAnnualSalary] [money] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tProfession2] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProfessionID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (1, N'Doctor                                            ', 200000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (2, N'Attorney                                          ', 350000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (3, N'Software Engineer                                 ', 120000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (4, N'Cybersecurity Consultant                          ', 110000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (5, N'Network Engineer                                  ', 111000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (6, N'Farmer                                            ', 200000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (7, N'Chef                                              ', 250000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (8, N'Truck Driver                                      ', 99000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (9, N'Wilderness Guide                                  ', 45000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (10, N'HVAC Technician                                   ', 79000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (11, N'Electrician                                       ', 80000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (12, N'TV Personality                                    ', 450000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (13, N'NFL Quarterback                                   ', 2000000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (14, N'Soccer Player                                     ', 4000000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (15, N'Electrical Engineer                               ', 130000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (16, N'Computer Engineer                                 ', 135000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (17, N'Business Owner                                    ', 4500000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (18, N'Politician                                        ', 20000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (19, N'City Manager                                      ', 90000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (20, N'Landscaper                                        ', 80000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (21, N'Pilot                                             ', 200000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (22, N'Insurance Salesperson                             ', 230000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (23, N'Interior Designer                                 ', 55000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (24, N'Architect                                         ', 600000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (25, N'IRS Agent                                         ', 99000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (26, N'Accountant                                        ', 120000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (27, N'Tax Preparer                                      ', 60000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (28, N'Spy                                               ', 0.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (29, N'Military Officer                                  ', 45000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (30, N'Veterinarian                                      ', 300000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (31, N'Roofer                                            ', 67000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (32, N'Arborist                                          ', 76000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (33, N'Painter                                           ', 60000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (34, N'Flight Attendant                                  ', 50000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (35, N'Amish Farmer                                      ', 10000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (36, N'Carpet Installer                                  ', 40000.0000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] ([ProfessionID], [Profession], [AverageAnnualSalary]) VALUES (37, N'Baker                                             ', 900000.0000)
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tProfession2] OFF
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_tProfession]    Script Date: 12/14/2021 10:48:42 AM ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tProfession2] ADD  CONSTRAINT [IX_tProfession2] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [Profession] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: A `CASE` expression returns a scalar value. In the above you try to return either the **`varchar`** values `'wow'`, `'nice'` or `'ok'` or the column `P.AverageAnnualSalary`. For the *latter* I would suggest a column containing someone's salary is not a `varchar` and so the other values are attempted to be converted to the column's data type (which appears to be `money`). Why are you trying to return string and numerical data in the same column? Why do you need the `ELSE` at all, as it's likely it would never be returned.

Comment: This is an intelligent question and natural thing to try when debugging. Cast the salary output to varchar and that way all the cases will have the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is simple and straight, in the case statement you are returning the charecter values excpet for the else case. so Just cast the else as string and it'll work

```
SELECT P.Profession AS Profession,
    CASE
        WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 200000
            THEN 'wow'
        WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 100000 
             AND P.AverageAnnualSalary <= 199999
            THEN 'nice'
        WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 0 
             AND P.AverageAnnualSalary <= 99999
            THEN 'ok'
        ELSE CAST(P.AverageAnnualSalary AS VARCHAR(50))
    END AS Description
FROM tProfession2 AS P
ORDER BY Profession ASC
```

Comment: I don't feel this is the right decision. The "description" and the value should be different columns. Though `AverageAnnualSalary` can only be returns if the row has the value `NULL`, `< 0` or *between* the values `199999` and `200000` or `99999` and `100000` (for example `99999.5`).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, your `ELSE` shouldn't be there. For the values you have, your `ELSE` would only be returned if `P.AverageAnnualSalary` is negative (unlikely, I *assume* you don't have staff that pay to work for you), `NULL` (pointless to then return it, might as well omit the `ELSE`), or between `199999` and `200000` (for example `199999.7`) or between `99999` and `100000` (for example `99999.5`).

You don't actually need the upper boundaries. For example if the first `WHEN` isn't true then the value is already implicitly *less than* `200000`. Then you remove the `ELSE` completely, thus removing the implicit conversion.

```sql
    CASE WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 200000 THEN 'wow'
         WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 100000 THEN 'nice'
         WHEN P.AverageAnnualSalary >= 0 THEN 'ok'
    END
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of a `CASE` expression is a single specific data type. SQL Server returns the ["highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types)

Using [data type precedence order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) you get "ok" and "nice" being converted to `money`

To solve this

```
ELSE CAST( P.AverageAnnualSalary AS VARCHAR( 30 ))
```